# Print a character from a variable using BIOS routine INT10h

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader, bios

Does somebody know what's wrong with the following code?

I cannot make it to work the way I want it.
I just want to print a single character of a variable (the letter 'h').

To do that I just copy contents using indirect addressing via the square brackets

> []

```
; Set BIOS print screen settings
mov ah, 0x0e ; Teletype
mov bh, 0  ; Page number
mov bl, 4  ; Red on black (00000100 - High 0000 is black, low 0100 is red)
mov cx, 1  ; Writes one character

; Printing to screen
mov al, [msg] ; Copy the contents of 'H' into 'al'; IT SEEMS THIS IS NOT WORKING!!!
jmp print_char ; Jump to executable code and do not let CPU step on DATA SECTION

; [BEG DATA SECTION]
  msg: db 'HELLO', 0
; [END DATA SECTION]

print_char:
int 0x10 ; Call BIOS routine to print the char located at 'al'

infinite_loop:
jmp $
times 510 -($-$$) db 0 ; Pad with 0 until byte 510
dw 0xAA55 ; MBR Boot code signature
```

What I get is a screen that prints "nothing" (Probably an ASCII non-printable character:
[image]

Comment: Can you a description of the result you get with your original code to your question?

Comment: Sure. I added a screenshot of the results. I am using QEMU.

It is working fine when I just use an immediate value.

Comment: Also helpful would be adding the commands you use to compile this piece, description of the platform and processor, and since this is a very short program, maybe a hex dump of your compiled file. I can see nothing illegal in your code, and start to think this is a question of dereferencing not working because of either wrong state of registers, or word alignment of your code.

Comment: If this is your complete code you are lacking an `org 0x7c00` at the top so that absolute offsets will start from 0x7c00 and not 0 within your code.  Without it is assumes offsets will be from a base of 0 when loaded in memory. As well you should set _DS_ to 0 before the rest of your code with `xor ax, ax` `mov ds, ax`. I have some bootloader tip in the [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705076/3857942)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks lot for you answer!!!
Indeed.
The problem was that it was necessary to execute `org 0x7c00` at the top of the program to work.
I will update my question for future reference and also will ook into your bootloader tips.

Thanks both of you for your time.

Comment: You should take your edit and create an answer so we can close the question off. It is okay to answer your own question and then accept your own answer.

Comment: Done.
Also what's the effect of DS particularly in the code above if set to 0? It should not affect anything as long as I do not use segments for addressing. Shouldn't it?

Comment: In real mode you are always using segments (most of the time they are implicit not explicit). When accessing a data value in memory in most cases it defaults to _DS_ register for the segment. For instance `mov al, [msg]` is actually the same as `mov al, [ds:msg]`. The segment and offset combine to form a physical address. The physical address is the (segment*16)+offset. A reasonable tutorial primer on real mode segment offset addressing can be found here: http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html

Comment: Worth noting that you can directly write to memory address 0xb8000 to modify the screen buffer directly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that it was lacking the following instruction at the top:

> org 0x7c00

More info regarding this in the answer of @Michael Petch.